# Selenium WebDriver - Invalid Cookie Domain Exception on increasing thread count to 20 but runs fine with 15

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit5, webdriver-manager

In my selenium automation framework I am running scripts in parallel with thread count 15, with thread count 15 it runs without any issues.
When I increase thread count to 20 or 30 then I am getting

```
  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: invalid cookie domain' exception.
```

I am using JAVA 1.8,  selenium = '3.141.59', webdrivermanager = '5.2.3' and Junit 5.

Can someone assist how to mitigate this issue.

Below is my page load and implicit wait settings

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without looking at the code, but it may very well be the performance problem hidden behind a red herring. The easiest way to reproduce the problem of `InvalidCookieDomainException` is to try and set the cookie before navigating to any webpage. For example:

```java
Webdriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
//driver.get(myWebApp); omitted.
driver.manage().addCookie(myCookie);
```

A plausible explanation could be that due to increased load, you are starting to hit various exceptions or timeouts, but they are somehow swallowed before reaching the line where the cookie is being set, and the exception is thrown with a bit misleading message

```java
WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().capabilities(options).create();
try {
    driver.get(unreachableOrUnresponsiveHost);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // swallows exception instead of failing due to an actual problem
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
// Fails, we are not in correct context yet
driver.manage().addCookie(myCookie);
```